# cstdlib not able to resolve using ::wcstombs

Tags: c++, fedora

I upgraded my system to fedora 33 after which I observed that stdlib.h was not able to resolve some data structures:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6545,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /home/ideepika/ceph5/ceph/src/rocksdb/include/rocksdb/cache.h:27,
                 from /home/ideepika/ceph5/ceph/src/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.h:12,
                 from /home/ideepika/ceph5/ceph/src/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.cc:10:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:935:5: error: expected initializer before ‘__attr_access’
  935 |     __attr_access ((__read_only__, 2));
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:940:3: error: expected initializer before ‘__attr_access’
  940 |   __attr_access ((__write_only__, 1, 3)) __attr_access ((__read_only__, 2));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:994:30: error: expected initializer before ‘__attr_access’
  994 |      __THROW __nonnull ((2)) __attr_access ((__write_only__, 2, 3));
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6545,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /home/ideepika/ceph5/ceph/src/rocksdb/include/rocksdb/cache.h:27,
                 from /home/ideepika/ceph5/ceph/src/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.h:12,
                 from /home/ideepika/ceph5/ceph/src/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.cc:10:
/usr/include/c++/10/cstdlib:154:11: error: ‘mbstowcs’ has not been declared in ‘::’
  154 |   using ::mbstowcs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/cstdlib:171:11: error: ‘wcstombs’ has not been declared in ‘::’
  171 |   using ::wcstombs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
```

the source of error is merely because of #include  and hence the source code from rocksdb doesn't looks suspicious.

Investigating... will update with relevant details, let me know if more details need to added

Comment: Weird. No such issues, whatsoever, on my F33. `<cstdlib>` gets include-ified just fine, by itself. The errors indicate that some large software package is getting built. Its likely doing something not entirely by the books, and is getting tripped up by the new compiler. Smells like "using namespace std".

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like your libc++ isn't compatible with your libc.

Comment: Unrelated: I'm postponing my F33 upgrade :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think Sam might be correct, checked with a colleague, they didn't face any issue with f33...

Comment: @DeepikaUpadhyay That's good to hear. I downloaded ceph5 and all its submodules and had a quick look around to see if I could find the culprit somewhere, but I ran out of time. :) I saw one `stdlib.h` or `stdint.h` inclusion in a C++ header in one submodule but that's probably not the cause.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for the trouble! I fixed those issues, semicolons it is!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out there is recent patch added to cstdlib: https://www.cygwin.com/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=12133

that might have been uncaught, I did not investigate the related files right now, but the adding the minimal changes patchset if someone else bumps to this issue...

```
diff --git a/stdlib.h b/stdlib.h
index f255e4a..d88ef89 100644
--- a/stdlib.h
+++ b/stdlib.h
@@ -931,10 +931,11 @@ extern int wctomb (char *__s, wchar_t __wchar) __THROW;
 
 /* Convert a multibyte string to a wide char string.  */
 extern size_t mbstowcs (wchar_t *__restrict  __pwcs,
-                       const char *__restrict __s, size_t __n) __THROW
+                       const char *__restrict __s, size_t __n) __THROW;
 /* Convert a wide char string to multibyte string.  */
 extern size_t wcstombs (char *__restrict __s,
-                       const wchar_t *__restrict __pwcs, size_t __n) __THROW
+                       const wchar_t *__restrict __pwcs, size_t __n)
+     __THROW;
 
 #ifdef __USE_MISC
 /* Determine whether the string value of RESPONSE matches the affirmation
@@ -988,7 +989,7 @@ extern char *ptsname (int __fd) __THROW __wur;
    terminal associated with the master FD is open on in BUF.
    Return 0 on success, otherwise an error number.  */
 extern int ptsname_r (int __fd, char *__buf, size_t __buflen)
-     __THROW __nonnull ((2))
+     __THROW __nonnull ((2));
```